# Error- Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run: bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am configuring docker for rails existing application and I am getting below error while running localhost:3000.

Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run: bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development

How to set up rake db:migrate in Docker
 docker-compose yml file

```
 version: '3'
volumes:  
postgres_data: {} 
services:
 redis:
  image: redis
 command: redis-server 
  ports:
  - "6379:6379"

app:    
 build:      
   context: .      
  dockerfile: /Users/admin/git/generic/deviceapp/docker/app/Dockerfile    
  depends_on:      
   - db  
db:    
image: postgres    
volumes:      
  - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data  
web:    
build:      
  context: .      
  dockerfile: /Users/admin/git/generic/deviceapp/docker/web/Dockerfile    
depends_on:      
  - app    
ports:      
  - 80:80
```

Database yml file

```
development:
adapter: postgresql
encoding: unicode
database: Myapp
pool: 5
username: san
password: test@123
host: db
```

DockerFile

```
FROM ruby:2.5.0
ENV RAILS_ROOT /Users/admin/git/generic/Myapplication
ENV REDIS_URL=redis://redis:6379/0
RUN mkdir -p $RAILS_ROOT 
# Set working directory
WORKDIR $RAILS_ROOT
# Setting env up
ENV RAILS_ENV='development'
ENV RACK_ENV='development'
# Adding gems
COPY Gemfile Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install
# Adding project files
COPY . .
RUN gem install bundler
RUN bundle install

COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["bundle", "exec", "puma", "-C", "config/puma.rb", "development", "- 
 b", "tcp://0.0.0.0:3000"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay, in my case, i resolved this problem telling to docker execute some bash commands in the `docker-compose.yml`. Like:

In your docker-compose:

```
# your_app_path/docker-compose.yml
...
web:
  build: 
  ...
  command: bash -c "build-scripts/container/web"
...
```

When your docker 'ups', the `build-scripts/container/web` will be executed.

Your `Dockerfile`, will be called on `docker-compose build`, you should not execute commands in this file.

Create the `build-scripts/container/web`, with this content:

```
#!/bin/bash

bundle check || bundle install

bundle exec rake db:setup && \
bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0' -P /tmp/rails.pid
```

You can choose to exchange the `rake db:setup` to `rake db:migrate` or something like this.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190060/discussion-on-answer-by-dimitrius-lachi-error-migrations-are-pending-to-resolv).

Comment: He doesnt have enough reputation to start a chat

Comment: Well that's why a mod have to start the chat. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/190060/?tab=access